# Сравнение эелементов массива, возвращаем строку с уникальными элементами JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы, сравнение

> Необходимо убрать повторения из списка хештегов и привести их к нижнему регистру. Результатом должна быть строка. Хештеги в строке должны быть разделены запятой и пробелом: `tag1, tag2, tag3`.

```
['web', 'coursera', 'JavaScript', 'Coursera', 'script', 'programming'] //Содержание массива
```

В голову пришел вариант с вложенным циклом.

```js
var elements = ['web', 'coursera', 'JavaScript', 'Coursera', 'script', 'programming'];
   

var filtered = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length;i++){
  var j = 1;
  if(elements[i].toLowerCase() !== elements[j].toLowerCase()){
  filtered.push(elements[i]);
    
  }
  j++;
  console.log(filtered);
}
```

Однако в результате выходит полный бред, не знаю как решить, направьте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var elements = ['web', 'coursera', 'JavaScript', 'Coursera', 'script', 'programming'];
var filtered = Array.from(new Set(elements.map(x => x.toLowerCase())));
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Где можно найти и прочитать про эти методы? Array,from , new Set и  x =>

Comment: Очень элегантное решений. Не использовал ранее в таком виде set. А вопрос по тому где найти очень странный, введя в интернете куча документации.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov, сначала спросил, потом подумал, уже читаю))

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще вариант

```js
var elements = ['web', 'coursera', 'JavaScript', 'Coursera', 'script', 'programming'];
var filtered = [];
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  var n = element.toLowerCase();
  if (filtered.indexOf(n) === -1) filtered.push(n);
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш измененный вариант.

```js
const elements = ['web', 'coursera', 'JavaScript', 'Coursera', 'script', 'programming'];
const filtered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  let hasInFiltered = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < filtered.length; j++) {
    if (elements[i].toLowerCase() === filtered[j].toLowerCase()) {
      hasInFiltered = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!hasInFiltered) {
    filtered.push(elements[i]);
  }
}

console.log(filtered);
```

Можно сделать немного проще.

```js
const elements = ['web', 'coursera', 'JavaScript', 'Coursera', 'script', 'programming'];
const filtered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  let hasInFiltered = filtered.some(s => s.toLowerCase() === elements[i].toLowerCase());
  if (!hasInFiltered) {
    filtered.push(elements[i]);
  }
}
console.log(filtered);
```

И последний вариант, с использованием объекта

```js
const elements = ['web', 'coursera', 'JavaScript', 'Coursera', 'script', 'programming'];
const filtered = Object.keys(elements.reduce((r, n) => {
  r[n.toLowerCase()] = true;
  return r;
}, {}));
console.log(filtered);
```